# Add class using script

Tags: javascript, html, fade

```
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 70,
            header = document.querySelector(".nb-navbar");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header, "smaller");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header, "smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header, "smaller");
            }
        }
    });
```

Hi guys, I need to do something what, when we scroll, when it reach center of the screen we need to add a class on a div. And we need to calculate from the bottom. That is from bottom when it reach a center or  at certain position the div need to add a class it's self. I have tried but it didn't work. Is there any other way or can you guys help with my script. Thanks :)

Comment: "*when we scroll, when it...*" - what is "it"? - "*...[reaches the] center of the screen we need to add a class on a div*" - which div?  "*I have tried but it didn't work*" - how did your attempt fail, what went wrong? Can you share enough of your [mcve] code that we can reproduce your problem, and see what you're working with? Have you looked at any [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) documentation (or [discussion](https://davidwalsh.name/intersection-observers))?

Comment: Your title said JQuery but your code doesn't include any jQuery code

Comment: Ok David Thomas, I can explain in detail.  Before that please open this test link http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/fade-text/test-fade.html

Comment: Why should anyone need to open a link in order to just understand your question? Create a [mcve] **in the question itself**

Comment: No. Post your code in your question; I appreciate - or at least *hope* - you're about to [edit] your question but looking at the problem in a live site is very different from looking at the minimal code, and as soon as your live site is fixed the problem - should - go away, making that example pointless and any answer that builds upon that live site's problem(s) becomes nonsensical

Comment: In this link you can see headings in left side. That is sticky there, let it be. But in right side you can see a long image. And also there are some text with the image. When it reach at the center of the screen ( whatever the screen height ) it should fade out. This should be happened for all the div there. This is exactly what I want. http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/fade-text/test-fade.html

Comment: I am looking at your link, tell me the exact requirement, on scroll what you want to do, by your question its confusing

Comment: Thanks  Atul, I need that text near image to be fade out when that reach at the center of th screen.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where `classie` is defined but if your just trying to add a class to the header

```
header = document.querySelector(".nb-navbar");
header.classList.add('smaller')
```

or perhaps

```
let hasClass = header.classList.contains('smaller');
header.classList.toggle('smaller', hasClass);
```

Comment: Hi Jordan Gaede, thank you very much for your reply :) In this link you can see headings in left side. That is sticky there, let it be. But in right side you can see a long image. And also there are some text with the image. When it reach at the center of the screen ( whatever the screen height ) it should fade out. This should be happened for all the div there. This is exactly what I want. http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/fade-text/test-fade.html